# php explode foreach strange line breaks

Tags: php, foreach, explode, line-breaks

I got a textarea filled with color codes like `000000` & `ffffff` each color is on a seperate line so it looks like:

```
000000
111111
222222
```

Now I am converting these to actual inline background colors with this:

```
$bgclass = $params->get('bgclass');
$bgcolors = $params->get('bgcolors');

$bglines = explode("\n", $bgcolors);
if ( !empty($bglines) ) {
  echo "<style>";
  foreach ( $bglines as $bgline ) {
    echo "." . $bgclass . "-" . $bgline . "{background:#" . $bgline . ";}" . "\r\n";
  }
  echo "</style>";
}
```

This is now outputting like this:

```
<style>
.bg-000000
{background:#000000
;}
.bg-111111
{background:#111111
;}
.bg-222222
{background:#222222
;}
</style>
```

How can I get the output to go like this:

```
<style>
.bg-000000{background:#000000;}
.bg-111111{background:#111111;}
.bg-222222{background:#222222;}
</style>
```

Comment: *trim* your values from the foreach. So they don't have the new line at the end anymore.

Comment: Or `explode` on `\r\n`.

Comment: @Rizier123 I tried what you said and did this `echo "." . $bgclass . "-" . trim($bgline) . "{background:#" . trim($bgline) . ";}" . "\r\n";`
Which works perfect. Thank you very much. Can you make it into a answer please?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I am not sure how I should do that? Should I do:
`$bglines = explode("\r\n", $bgcolors);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver My bad I made a typo that's why it gave a error `/t/n` ain't going to cut it. :-) with `/r/n` like you said it is working. Thanks man. So which is best to do? What is best practice? And could you make it also in a  answer?

Comment: @purple11111 You can use both. I would probably go with `"\r\n"` as delimiter for `explode()`, since the code is a bit more clear.

Comment: Please don't put a solution inside your question.

Comment: Added 3.  I personally would use `file()`.

Comment: @Rizier123 I removed the solution as it more clear that way. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `explode()` on `\r\n` instead:

```
$bglines = explode("\r\n", $bgcolors);
```

Another option would be to `trim()` it:

```
$bglines = explode("\n", $bgcolors);
$bglines = array_map('trim', $bglines);
```

If this were a file (as I originally thought) then I would use `file()` to read the file into an array and strip the line endings:

```
$bglines = file('/path/to/file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: I don't have a file. Not sure where you get that from? But still very useful information to know. Thanks man. But especially the `\r\n` part is brilliant it is what made it work for me.

Comment: A third option is to simply `str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $str)`, and then just `explode("\n", $str)` and then you don't have to worry about which line ending is used or trimming off missed `\r`s,.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what is wrong with the approach you've posted, but this might help you out.

```
<?php
$bglines = explode(PHP_EOL, $bgcolors);
$styles = [];
foreach($bglines as $bgline) {
$trimmed = trim($bgline);
    $styles[] = sprintf(".%s-%s{background : #%s;}%s", $bgclass, $trimmed, $trimmed, PHP_EOL);
}
echo "<style>" . implode($styles) . "</style>";
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. I am not sure what you are doing here. It probably works great but I can't read it. Which ain't your fault off course but therefore I am not using it.